# select minute avg in one minute increments

Tags: sql

I am trying to come up with a way to do the following in a single SQL.

I would like to select all times between 09:00 and 17:30 in one minute increments without using a for loop. Is there a way to do it?

```
select avg(price), Date(timecolumn)
from table 
where Time(timeColumn) >= '09:00:00'
and Time(timeColumn) <= '09:01:00'
```

Comment: Tell us which Database system your using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to group by date, hour, and minute.

```
SELECT AVG(price), DATE(timecolumn), HOUR(timecolumn), MINUTE(timecolumn)
FROM `table` 
WHERE TIME(timeColumn) >= '09:00:00' AND TIME(timeColumn) <= '17:01:00'
GROUP BY DATE(timecolumn), HOUR(timecolumn), MINUTE(timecolumn)
```

Comment: Of course it's so simple that I couldn't see the solution immediately :)

Comment: @xdazz - I'm not sure what DB he is using - but casting a column or modifying with (UPPER/LOWER etc) will negate the index (in informix anyway) - hence cause the query engine to run a sequential scan for this SELECT. Might get slow with a large recordset if this is true for the engine he/she is using

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the big hurdle here is you want to keep (and return) rows for the zeroes (or NULLs) - that is, one-minute increments with no rows in your `table` table.

You might want to consider adding a table to your database with times in it. Something like:

```
FullTime TIME,
Hour INT,
Minute INT,
Second INT
```

86400 rows gets you precision down to the second and you can put indexes on it.

Then you can just join with this table:

```
SELECT AVG(Price), DATE(timeColumn)
FROM times
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable ON times.FullTime = myTable.timeColumn
WHERE times.timeColumn BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '17:30:00'
AND times.Seconds = 0
GROUP BY times.FullTime
```

Comment: Great solution to combine the two step approach I am using now.